# Popover not showing on first click for dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to get a popover for my webpage. It doesn't work for me on the first click but however works fine thereafter. I realize that it gets instantiated on the first click and therefore doesn't show up. Is there a better way to instantiate it, given that I'm using id's that are generated at runtime. I have looked at similar questions but they don't seem to work for me. Here is the code I have written,

```
    <table id="userInfo">
  <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>UserGroup</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @userdetails.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a class='user_show_more' data-placement='left' id='<%= user %>'>[+]</a>
              <!-- popover table starts here -->
              <div id="<%= user %>_popover" style="display: none">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>UserNames</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <%= user['name'] %>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- popover ends here -->
          <% user['group'] %>
        </td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my javascript code looks like this,

```
    $('.user_show_more').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this)
        var popover_id = '#'+$this.attr("id");
        $(popover_id).popover({
            html : true,
            content: function() {
                var popover = '#'+$this.attr("id")+'_popover';
                return $(popover).html();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe you still need to call show after initializing the popover. Add "$(popover_id).popover('show');" to the end of your click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two click handlers to your popovers. The first one uses 'one' and the second one uses 'on'.

https://jsbin.com/kegovebufu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

HTML

```
  <button type="button"
          class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
          data-toggle="popover" 
          id="Temp"
          >Stuff</button> 


  <script type="text/html" id="Temp_popover">
   <div>  
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>UserNames</th> 
          </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>blah</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>      
  </script>
```

Javascript

```
    function PopoverClick()
{
  $(this).popover('toggle'); 
}




$('[data-toggle="popover"]').one('click',function(e){

  console.log('once');
  var _this = $(this);


  _this.popover(
  {
    html:true,
    content: function()
    {
      return $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'_popover').html();         
    },
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement:'right'    
  }).popover('show');  

  _this.on('click',PopoverClick);

});
```

Comment: It works on the first click and doesn't work after that.

Comment: @imuqtadir try this instead

Comment: @imuqtadir also are you trying to optimize the page load or what is your end goal?